# How to compare total effect of three variables across two regressions that use different subsamples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stata

I am running the following regression in Stata on two sub-samples (Low and High groups):
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 {ln(1+New\:co-investors)}_{i,t} = \alpha_0  &+ \alpha_{1}PreSuccess_{i,t-1} + \alpha_{2}PreSuccess_{i,t-2} + \alpha_{3}PreSuccess_{i,t-3} \\
         &+ \beta_{1}PostSuccess_{i,t+1} + \beta_{2}PostSuccess_{i,t+2} + \beta_{3}PostSuccess_{i,t+3} \\
                 &+\mu_{i} + \gamma_{t} +\epsilon_{it} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Therefore I have 3 $\beta$s for low and 3 $\beta$s for high regressions.

***Question***: I would like to test if the total post effect ($PostSuccess_{i,t=1,2,3}$) for low group is different from that of high group i.e. $PostSuccess_{Low,i,t=1,2,3} = PostSuccess_{High,i,t=1,2,3} $  Is there a way to do this?

*Note:* I agree that I can run one regression on the full sample (instead of two on sub-samples) with a dummy for *High group* and interact it with *PostSuccess* variables. And, perform an F-test. But I would like to know if this could be done in two regressions as it would make the writing up the results easier.

Also, note that the dependent variable is same in both regressions and the data is different in each case. Hence a SUR would not work.

***Background:*** I am studying the impact of success (shock) at time *t* on an investor's network connections. The idea is that before the shock there should be no increase in connections (*Pre* dummies should be insignificant) and after there should be a significant increase. The regressions are run on a matched sample where treatment group is those who experienced a success and control is those who did not experience a shock.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me to an appropriate test (would be wonderful if there is a Stata routine to do this).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata has a handy command called `suest` that allows you to combine estimation results from separate models (both parameter vectors and associated (co)variance matrices) into a single parameter vector and simultaneous (co)variance matrix of the sandwich/robust type. This joint (co)variance matrix is appropriate even if the estimates were obtained on the same or on overlapping data. The estimation commands can even be different (say a probit or a linear regression).

Something like that can also be done with Stata's `gsem` (example [here](http://blog.stata.com/2014/08/18/using-gsem-to-combine-estimation-results/)), or via "stacking". The [third example](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rsuest.pdf#page=13) in the manual has an example of the latter approach that can also be done without Stata. However, this route is somewhat more limited (ancillary parameters parameters are constrained to be equal between the stacked models and you can't compare different statistical models).

In your case all three are feasible, but I will focus on `suest` here. You can use it to test equality of coefficients across equations like this:

```
. webuse income, clear

. regress inc edu exp if male

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =       110
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 107)       =     20.05
       Model |  639.919043         2  319.959521   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  1707.31485       107  15.9562136   R-squared       =    0.2726
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2590
       Total |   2347.2339       109  21.5342559   Root MSE        =    3.9945

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         edu |   1.841002    .383369     4.80   0.000     1.081018    2.600986
         exp |   1.590727   .3569439     4.46   0.000     .8831278    2.298327
       _cons |   1.783822   .3818906     4.67   0.000     1.026769    2.540876
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store Male

. regress inc edu exp if !male

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =       167
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 164)       =     43.30
       Model |  1418.47853         2  709.239266   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  2686.09306       164  16.3786162   R-squared       =    0.3456
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.3376
       Total |  4104.57159       166  24.7263349   Root MSE        =    4.0471

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         edu |   2.475213   .3160483     7.83   0.000     1.851165    3.099261
         exp |   1.354081   .3043211     4.45   0.000     .7531885    1.954974
       _cons |   1.250719   .3132966     3.99   0.000     .6321043    1.869334
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store Female

. suest Male Female

Simultaneous results for Male, Female

                                                Number of obs     =        277

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Male_mean    |
         edu |   1.841002   .3911029     4.71   0.000     1.074454    2.607549
         exp |   1.590727   .3320187     4.79   0.000     .9399827    2.241472
       _cons |   1.783822   .3829948     4.66   0.000     1.033166    2.534478
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Male_lnvar   |
       _cons |   2.769848   .1328349    20.85   0.000     2.509497      3.0302
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Female_mean  |
         edu |   2.475213   .3093986     8.00   0.000     1.868803    3.081623
         exp |   1.354081   .2982058     4.54   0.000     .7696084    1.938554
       _cons |   1.250719   .3122779     4.01   0.000      .638666    1.862773
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Female_lnvar |
       _cons |   2.795977   .0976384    28.64   0.000     2.604609    2.987344
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. suest Male Female, coefl

Simultaneous results for Male, Female

                                                Number of obs     =        277

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.  Legend
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Male_mean    |
         edu |   1.841002  _b[Male_mean:edu]
         exp |   1.590727  _b[Male_mean:exp]
       _cons |   1.783822  _b[Male_mean:_cons]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Male_lnvar   |
       _cons |   2.769848  _b[Male_lnvar:_cons]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Female_mean  |
         edu |   2.475213  _b[Female_mean:edu]
         exp |   1.354081  _b[Female_mean:exp]
       _cons |   1.250719  _b[Female_mean:_cons]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Female_lnvar |
       _cons |   2.795977  _b[Female_lnvar:_cons]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test ([Male_mean]edu = [Female_mean]edu) ([Male_mean]exp = [Female_mean]exp)

 ( 1)  [Male_mean]edu - [Female_mean]edu = 0
 ( 2)  [Male_mean]exp - [Female_mean]exp = 0

           chi2(  2) =    1.79
         Prob > chi2 =    0.4082
```

The `coefl` option is useful for figuring out what the coefficients are called, though it obscures some results.

I am not clear what the total effect is in your notation, but you can test that the sums of two coefficients are equal in the two samples with either of these:

```
. test ([Male_mean]edu + [Male_mean]exp = [Female_mean]edu + [Female_mean]exp)

 ( 1)  [Male_mean]edu + [Male_mean]exp - [Female_mean]edu - [Female_mean]exp = 0

           chi2(  1) =    0.39
         Prob > chi2 =    0.5336

. lincom ([Male_mean]edu + [Male_mean]exp) - ([Female_mean]edu + [Female_mean]exp)

 ( 1)  [Male_mean]edu + [Male_mean]exp - [Female_mean]edu - [Female_mean]exp = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |  -.3975647   .6386634    -0.62   0.534    -1.649322    .8541926
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the p-values are the same.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response @Masterov. I was unsure if this can be done using Stata's suest. It worked.